# Filtering by specific dates in the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem where i am trying to exclude the first ten days of each month from a query.  My date is in format yyyy-mm-dd.  How is the best method to exclude days 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10 from each month in the query?

I am using the Wide World Importers database.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In ANSI SQL, you can use `extract()`:

```
where extract(day from datecol) > 10
```

Some databases do not support `extract()` but have a `day()` function:

```
where day(datecol) > 10
```

Comment: you mean `day(datecol)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use day function

where day(ColumnName) > 10

Answer (score 0):

You should use date functions like this SQL server.

```sql
SELECT column_name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE day(column_name[datatype = DATETIME]) = (int day) 
AND month(column_name[datatype = DATETIME]) < (int month) 
AND year(column_name[datatype = DATETIME]) > (int year)
```